# How to compute the remainder of a very large number (string with 1 mi digits) in the division by 1500

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering if there is a trick with number theory to compute this remainder without need to implement a BigInt division algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, it's easy!

I can iterate over all digits, adding each parcel...
Using the properties:

1) (a+b) mod c = (a mod c + b mod c) mod c

2) (a*b) mod c = (a mod c * b mod c) mod c

The power of ten can be increased mod 1500 each step.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, just check these three things:

**Divisibility by 1500**

1. it has to be divisible by 100 (last two digits must be `00`)
2. it has to be divisible by 5 (third digit from right has to be `0` or `5`)
3. it has to be divisible by 3 (iterate over all digits, sum them, and the result has to be divisible by 3)

And if you want to know the remainder, its again simple:

**Check for divisible by 5 and get remainder**

1. get remainder from last 4 digits after division by `500`, it will be from `0` to `499`.

**Check for divisible by 3 and get remainder**

2. iterate over all digits, sum them, and get remainder from that after division by `3`, it will be from `0` to `2`.
3. and depending from this remainder increase the remainder from 1st step by this remainder multiplied by `500`.

**Example 1**

`1234567890 % 1500 = 390`

1. `7890 % 500 = 390`
2. `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 0 = 45` and `45 % 3 = 0`, so nothing has to be added to `390` and the result is then `390`.

**Example 2**

`12345678901 % 1500 = 901`

1. `8901 % 500 = 401`
2. `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 0 + 1 = 46` and `46 % 3 = 1`, so we have to add `1 * 500` to the result from 1st step, so `401 + 1 * 500 = 901`.

**Example 3**

`1357913579 % 1500 = 1079`

1. `3579 % 500 = 79`
2. `1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 50` and `50 % 3 = 2`, so we have to add `2 * 500` to the result from 1st step, so `79 + 2 * 500 = 1079`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: but I don't want to know if it is divisible or not, I want the remainder...
the answer I gave can do it, but I was looking for something smarter

Comment: Thanks... But, can you explain this logic? Why this algorithm is correct?

Comment: @matheuscscp :-) as I was explaining divisibility by 1500, its the same, you have to get the remainder by checking divisibility by 3 and 5 and then multiply by 100. Trust me, its correct, I spent almost hour figuring out how it can be done :-)

Comment: Dude, this solution doesn't work... I implemented the solution I gave (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28454789/1972599) and I got "Correct Answer". I implemented your solution and I got "Wrong Answer".

Comment: I can even give some nice counterexamples:

1 % 1500 = 1
1 % 500 = 1
1 % 3 = 1
But 1 + 500*1 != 1

1501 % 1500 = 1
1501 % 500 = 1
1501 % 3 = 1
But again 1 + 500*1 != 1